# Concatenating Primes

Tags: code-golf, string, primes

**Challenge:**

You are given a string containing only digits. Your task is to output the minimum number of primes which must be concatenated to form the string. If this is impossible, output `0`.

**Test Cases:**

Input -> Output:

```
252 -> 3
235 -> 2
92 -> 0
31149 -> 2
```

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55406/20469)

Comment: Can there be leading zeroes?

Comment: Yes, there can be leading zeroes.

Comment: Can we take a list of digits?

Comment: What happens if there are leading zeroes?

Comment: Format of input/output?

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>123</s> <s>121</s> 120 bytes

```js
f=(s,v)=>(p=n=>--n-1?s%n&&p(n):1)(s)||[...s].map((_,i)=>!(n=i&&(a=f(s.slice(0,i)))&&(b=f(s.slice(i)))&&a+b)|n>v?0:v=n)|v
```

*Saved a byte thanks to @Neil!*

### Explanation

Takes a single string as input. Due to the prime checking method (recursive trial division), the greatest number that can be safely checked is `13840`. Some numbers above this will fail due to the maximum call stack size being exceeded. It does, however, finish instantly for every case it can handle.

```js
f=(s,v)=>
  (p=n=>--n-1?s%n&&p(n):1)(s) // if s is prime, return 1
  ||[...s].map((_,i)=>        // else for each index in s, split s into 2
    !(n=i&&                   // v = return value (initialised to undefined)
      (a=f(s.slice(0,i)))&&
      (b=f(s.slice(i)))&&
      a+b
    )|n>v?0:v=n               // if i, a, b and n are all > 0 and !(n > v), v = n
  )|v                         // cast v to an integer and return it

// Test
var testCases = [ "252", "235", "92", "3149", "24747" ];
document.write("<pre>" + testCases.map(c => c + ": " + f(c)).join("\n"));
```

Comment: Is it me or can you change `i?(a=...)&&(b=...)&&a+b:0` to `i&&(a=...)&&(b=...)&&a+b`?

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
0in:"GUtZq@Z^V10ZA=a?x@.
```

It takes a few seconds for some of the test cases.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MGluOiJHVXRacUBaXlYxMFpBPWE_eEAu&input=JzIzNSc)

#### Explanation

```
0       % Push 0
in:     % Take input. Generate array [1,2,...,N] where N is input length
"       % For each. In each iteration the number of used primes is increased
  GU    %   Push input. Convert to number
  tZq   %   Duplicate. Array of primes smaller than the input
  @     %   Push number of primes to bes tested in this iteration
  Z^    %   Cartesian power
  V     %   Convert to 2D array. Each row is a combination of primes
  10ZA  %   Convert each row to base 10, disregarding spaces
  =a    %   Do any of the results equal the input number? 
  ?     %   If so
    x   %     Remove the 0 that's at the bottom of the stack
    .   %     Break for each loop
        %   Implicitly end if
        % Implicitly end for each
        % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
lhf.AmP_sdTa./zY
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lhf.AmP_sdTa.%2FzY&input=252&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=252%0A235%0A92%0A31149&debug=0).

Comment: In its newer form, this one counts 0 and 1 as primes.  However, before the edit, it did not.

Comment: @poi830 fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
lhaf!f!P_sYT./zY
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lhaf%21f%21P_sYT.%2FzY&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=252%0A235%0A92%0A1&debug=0)

Explanation to follow.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + coreutils, <s>169</s> <s>158</s> 149 bytes

```
c()
{
test $1||echo a
for i in `seq ${#1}`
do factor ${1::$i}|grep -q ': \w*$'&&printf b%s\\n `c ${1:$i}`
done
}
c $1|sort|sed '/a/!d;s/..//;q'|wc -c
```

We count in unary, outputting a line with one `b` for each prime and a terminating `a` at the end of line (so that `printf` has a token to work with).

The primality test is `factor $n | grep -q ': \w*$'`, which determines whether the number has exactly one prime factor.

We recursively partition the input; if the left half is prime, we filter the results of the right half by adding one to each value.  Returning `a` for a zero-length input terminates the recursion.

Finally, we take all the results and sort to find the shortest (ignoring any that don't have the `a` to indicate success); we must delete two (for the inserted `a` and for the newline), then count characters to give the result.

#### Tests

```
$ for i in 252 235 92 31149 111; do echo "$i:"$'\t'"$(./77623.sh $i)"; done
252:    3
235:    2
92:     0
31149:  2
111:    0
```

I added `111` to the tests to show that `1` is correctly considered non-prime.

Comment: I was going to suggest [this](http://ideone.com/QESnpZ). Most of my modifications are probably obsolete now, but others should still work.

Comment: @Dennis - I like the `c` to generate the final `0`.  Not so keen on the copious stderr, though.  You're welcome to use (versions of) my answer as a basis for your own if you like.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>142</s> 135 bytes

```
Min[Length/@Select[Join@@@Permutations/@IntegerPartitions@Length[a=#],And@@PrimeQ@*FromDigits/@a~Internal`PartitionRagged~#&]]/.∞->0&
```

As you can see, Mathematica was not built for this task. Takes a list of digits.

Comment: Can you use `And@@` instead of `AllTrue`? Should save 4-5 bytes.

Comment: `Flatten[#,1]`=`Join@@@#`

Comment: Um...gives error and wrong answer on 133...you did use all test cases, right?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Golfed and clarified.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¬∞ÿ╔>÷▀↓☼~î☼ó♀RàEx
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=aaec98c93ef6df190f7e8c0fa20c52854578&i=%22252%22%0A%22235%22%0A%2292%22%0A%2231149%22&m=2)