# Within Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci

**The Challenge**

Given an integer input, return the first Fibonacci number that contains the input within itself along with the index of that Fibonacci number (indexes starting at 0 or 1 - up to you, but please mention which in your answer). For example, if given the input of 12, the program would return `26: 121393` as 12 is found within the number (**12**1393) and it is at index 26 of the Fibonacci numbers.

**Examples**

Given the input:

```
45
```

Your program should output:

```
33: 3524578
```

Input:

```
72
```

Output:

```
54: 86267571272
```

Input:

```
0
```

Output:

```
0: 0
```

Input:

```
144
```

Output:

```
12: 144
```

**Scoring**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

Comment: Can we choose to have 1-indexing instead?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Sure, I updated the challenge. :)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but pretty close to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126525/print-the-nth-fibonacci-number-containing-the-nth-fibonacci-number) challenge.

Comment: The 12th fibonacci number is 144, so the last test case should be 12: 144.

Comment: Thread over on [math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1845099) regarding whether Fibonacci sequence is normal or not (this question presumes it is).

Comment: @fireflame241 Good catch! I have fixed the example. :)

Comment: Do we have to use a colon as a separator? Can we output an array/list?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I think this question even goes a bit further in its presumtion than that thread. That thread would imply that every natural number would appear at some point in the constant, but this would allow overlapping between two numbers: `32` would be in `8,1[3,2]1` already instead of in `832040`.

Comment: [Related question on math.SE about whether this has a solution for any x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374503/do-the-fibonacci-numbers-contain-any-run-of-digits)

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Good distinction. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Shaggy the colon is not mandatory, it's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
0ÆḞ©w¥1#;®
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//MMOG4biewql3wqUxIzvCrv///zMz)

#### How it works

```
0ÆḞ©w¥1#;®  Main link. Argument: n

0           Set the return value to 0.
       #    Call the second link to the left with arguments k = 0, 1, 2, ... until
      1     one match has been found.
     ¥        Combine the two links to the left into a dyadich chain.
 ÆḞ             Compute the k-th Fibonacci number...
   ©              and copy it to the register.
    w           Yield 1 if n occurs inside the Fibonacci number, 0 otherwise.
         ®  Yield the value stored in the register.
        ;   Concatenate the index and the Fibonacci number.
```

Comment: You used the same trick as mine. :)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer As yours?

Comment: Didn't post it, but generally I didn't use `D` either...

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=0,a=0,b=1:`n`in`a`and(i,a)or f(n,i+1,b,a+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYvBCoAgEAXvfcXeSnpBihEE9i2uhLRQW0SXvt48zGWYub93v9SVksPBZ9qYFBJGcCUFu0SNopEj69YJ2FwP5a4mvUUC98mUXJWQKPkJs8MI6/3SEN2P6EuCdlhb1ElMmd0P)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 30 bytes

```
{first :kv,/$_/,(0,1,*+*...*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFhCkAwAAbQq3xpiVkzGgrbVZYfVkK0SWnt7PPevbqjT@eH3EKlYDfnH4z7y2pialYI1jBaUc45LWOa4JcPGTFQGsGCmJjBXg6z7DC0EGik1FP6AQ)

`first` is a function that returns the first element of a sequence that passes a test, and it conveniently takes a `:kv` adverb that tells it to return both the key (index) and the matching value.

Comment: Assuming you can return a [Pair](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pair) object, you can use the `:p` adverb instead of `:kv`.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 104 bytes

```
@set/an=x=0,y=1
:l
@call set t=%%x:%1=%%
@if "%t%"=="%x%" set/an+=1,x+=y,y=x-y&goto l
@echo %n%: %x%
```

Works for `n=0..45` due to the limited range of Batch's integer arithmetic. Explanation: Batch doesn't have a built-in match test, but it does have an operator that can replace literal strings with other literal strings, so for example `if "%s:l=%"=="%s%"` is true if `%s%` is not empty but does not contain `l`. The use of `call` is then a trick to substitute `%1` (the input) into the replacement operator, however `call` doesn't work on control flow statements so an intermediate temporary assignment is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
³DẇÆḞ¬
0‘Ç¿µ,ÆḞ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QZpeHu9oPtz3cMe/QGi6DRw0zDrcf2n9oqw5Y6P///@ZGAA)

Comment: 43 seconds too late

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6, 68 chars

```
n=>eval('for(q=x=0,y=1;!`${x}`.match(n);++q)[x,y]=[y,x+y];q+": "+x')
```

Test:

```js
f=n=>eval('for(q=x=0,y=1;!`${x}`.match(n);++q)[x,y]=[y,x+y];q+": "+x')
console.log([45,72,0,144].map(f).join`
`)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 76 bytes

```
f=lambda n,l=[1,0]:str(n)in str(l[1])and(len(l)-2,l[1])or f(n,[l[0]+l[1]]+l)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 133 bytes

```
a 0b 1i 0☁️a 1010b➕a ba➖b ai➕1ii 10a 10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f9h/oRuhQ/zZzUBid52EHfah/lTFoE4QLwuUcEARCUpGIKoTBBvSuOjGY3vd/QDWb1AvDBRwRAkuhCodSqIBdGY9Gje1ESFJLAZj@ZNS1JIBBsAFDXMBLI6P8yf0QDSlQnWDWFDTOrt/A8iuLg@zO9vBLuKS0EB5CYFE1MusDQA)

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 39 bytes

```
{⍺←0⋄∨/(⍕⍵)⍷⍕x←1∧+∘÷/0,⍺/1:⍺,x⋄(1+⍺)∇⍵}
```

Using tail recursion. Don't attempt 72, it'll break your machine because its recalculating fibonacci all over every call.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR727gJTBo@6WRx0r9DUe9U591LtV81HvdiCrAihj@KhjufajjhmHt@sb6AAV6xtaAUmdCqAGDUNtIFPzUUc7UEst0DwFE1MA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>79</s> <s>78</s> 75 bytes

-1 byte by *Step Hen*

-3 bytes by *Neil*

```
i=>eval('d=a=b=1;while(!~(a+"").indexOf(i)){c=b;b=a+b;a=c;‌​d++};d+": "+a')
```

Comment: You can use `eval()` instead of `{ return}` to save a byte, and you can drop the `t=` since you aren't using recursion: `i=>eval('d=a=b=1;while(!~(a+"").indexOf(i+""){c=b;b=a+b;a=c;d++};d+": "+a')`

Comment: `String.prototype.indexOf` automatically converts its parameter to a string, no need to do it explicitly. Also you appear to have copied @StepHen's typo (you have more `(`s than `)`s).

Comment: @Neil woops my bad

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 119 bytes

1-indexed

```
(T=ToString;If[(h=#)==0,"0:0",a=#&@@Select[k=T/@(Array[Fibonacci,9#]),StringContainsQ[#,T@h]&];Min@Position[k,a]":"a])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcyxCsIwEADQXwkNlAYCFhfRcnAiCA5CpdlChjO0zVFNoM3i10fB/fHelAP7rUxQGgMmDXnlOHe3yTYBpAJoddWeRFtpAlkjDuNr9NkuYHbYnNeVPvbKzxTJe9ZH6ZT@D5cUM3HcHlZqg8HVrrtzxD5tnDlFu2hygpwSdel/PgucBB725Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 13 bytes

```
╗1⌠F$╜@c⌡╓i;F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9hY3R1YWxsef//4pWXMeKMoEYk4pWcQGPijKHilZNpO0b//yIxMiI)

Explanation:

```
╗1⌠F$╜@c⌡╓i;F
╗              save input in register 0
 1⌠F$╜@c⌡╓     smallest non-negative integer n where the following function returns truthy:
   F$            nth Fibonacci number, stringified
     ╜@c         count occurrences of input
          i;F  flatten the list, duplicate the index, and push the Fibonacci number at that index
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 65 bytes

```
f=function(x,n=1,a=1,b=0)`if`(grepl(x,b),c(b,n-1),f(x,n+1,a+b,a))
```

Standard recursion to generate Fibnums, but instead of terminating based on `n`, terminates when `b` matches the regex `x`. This actually works surprisingly well. I assumed that using regex with numerics would require a lot of hassle converting them to strings, but that doesn't seem to be necessary :)

This also has to overshoot the recursion by 1 step, by checking on `b` instead of `a` and then substracting `1` from `n`. This is to make sure `f(0)` works properly.

This fails for most values when input exceeds `1001`, because of maxint. If we replace `a` and `b` for bigints, this works for higher inputs (current testing is at `x = 11451`)

```
f=function(x,n=1,a=gmp::as.bigz(1),b=gmp::as.bigz(0))`if`(grepl(x,b),c(b,n-1),f(x,n+1,a+b,a))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 99 bytes

```cs
n=>{int a=0,b=1,c,d=0;for(;b.ToString().IndexOf(n.ToString())<0;c=a,a=b,b+=c,d++);return d+": "+b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYtNC8IgGIDv@xUvnRRtLCKCzC5BEBQRBZ3VuSHUK6iLYuy3r9WpQ12fDxPHxgfbN9FhDadnTPYmMnNVMcKxzWJSyRm4e1fCXjkktM02DZqlw8QhpjBcK6hlj3LVDgyULLiWE254KQtR@UCEzs/@9CkJzbdY2sehIvgF6bIQRiqupOaayWFljIpgUxMQSjZawIhp0fUiW3uM/mrzS3DJ7hxaUpMppb/F/J@YzN6m6/oX)

Takes input as an integer, returns a string with the output.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 84 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f=0:scanl(+)1f
g n=filter(isInfixOf(show n).show.snd)(zip[0..]f)!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixCsIwEIDhvU9x3RLE0DoW0sUuBcHBURyCTdLD9FpyB4ovH@vw88E/O375lErBZVuzwODEmQuyVME2HT8dJXXQbagikA2YxGeFPFLAzzUontc3kDZ/DdOk1Re3e2PMI@i6bsrikMBC9HJeSTwJQ99b2DKSgIG4p7J3E3Qd3GS/EY49jCS6tKcf)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @JustinMariner*

```
_Å¬øU}a@[XMgX]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P/5w66E1h3eE1iY6REf4pkfE/v9vbgQA)

#### Explanation

```
_Å¬øU}a@[XMgX]      Implicit: U = input integer
      a@            For each integer X in [0, 1, 2, ...]:
        [XMgX]        take [X, Fibonacci(X)].
_    }a             Return the first pair where
 Å                    all but the first item
  ¬                   joined on the empty string (simply returns Fibonacci(X) as a string)
   øU                 contains U.
                    Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: 14 bytes: `_Å¬øU}a@[XMgX]`. Using `s1 q ` to get last item, which allows dropping the `<space>s`

Comment: @JustinMariner That's... that's genius :-)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 80 bytes

```
<?php for($a=1,$b=$n=0;strpos($a=-$a+$b=$a+$b,"$argv[1]")<-1;$n++);echo"$n: $a";
```

The script is quite straightforward, simply storing the current and next terms of the sequence in $a and $b throughout. To allow for the 0th term of 0, $a and $b are initially assigned the values for the -1th term (1) and 0th term (0) respectively.

Both values are recalculated in a single expression, which is two assignments in one; effectively:

```
$b = $a + $b; // The next term is the sum of the two previous terms
$a = $b - $a; // The current term is now recalculated from the next and the previous
```

If the input value matches the beginning of the term, the strpos() function will return 0 (which is falsey and would give a false negative), but in the Wonderphul World of PHP, although `false == 0` is true and `false < 0` is false, `false < -1` is true! And so, using this comparison saves five bytes compared to `!==false`.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>163</s> 141 bytes

```php
<?php $x=fgets(STDIN);$b=[0,1];if($x<1)$b=[0];for(;($c=count($b)-1)&&strpos($b[$c],$x)===false;){$b[]=$b[$c]+$b[$c-1];}die($c.': '.$b[$c]);?>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBpcI2LT21pFgjOMTF00/TWiXJNtpAxzDWOjNNQ6XCxlATLBBrnZZfpGGtoZJsm5xfmleioZKkqWuoqaZWXFJUkF8M5EarJMfqqFRo2trapiXmFKdaa1YDBWNtITLaYEoXaGxtSmYq0Bg9dSsFdT2IpKa1vd3//wA)

Uses `$b[0] = 0;` and `$b[1] = 1;` for the start of fib sequence

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 67 + 1 (-p) = 68 bytes

```perl
@f=(0,1);push@f,$f[-1]+$f[-2]while($f[-2]!~/$_/);$_=--$#f." $f[-1]"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hzVbDQMdQ07qgtDjDIU1HJS1a1zBWG0QZxZZnZOakakDYinX6KvH6mtYq8ba6uirKaXpKChC1Sv//G/zLLyjJzM8r/q/ra6pnYGjwX7cAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 93 bytes

```php
for($a[0]=$a[1]++;!strpos(" $a[$i]","$argv[1]");$a[$i+2]=$a[$i+1]+$a[$i++]);echo"$i: $a[$i]";
```

Simple loop through the Fibonacci sequence. The check for our input number is done in `strpos(" $a[$i]","$argv[1]")`; the extra space is because `strpos` will return false-y if the 'needle' is found at the beginning of the string. We end if the input is found and echo out the required string.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSow1ibYGkYay2trVicUlRQX6xhpICUEQlM1ZJR0klsSi9DCirpGkNFtM2AisHMoA6IAztWE3r1OSMfCWVTCuYRuv///8bGgEA)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 105 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(do((a 0 b)(b 1(+ a b))(i 0(1+ i)))((search(#1=format()"~a"x)(#1#()"~a"a))(#1#()"~a: ~a"i a))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzRCoJAEEV/5bIS3UECN1eCoP5ldIsWtBX1oSd/3SZ86O3MHc7p@jSPG/ucRzzzhIT0xpGhweWMJqCCD0EQM2jvQRcscGsdcbpj9bWuB2cOraBDG5UfYcykmtgKW3iWUENhQkVfIokx54dO3YuFv@1VilvVmVz4YmeV/3GFDQk2iWy/wPYF)